# How do I use terminal to install plugins and libraries for PHP (MAMP)?

Tags: php, terminal, mamp, phpquery

**Can you walk me through the installation of a library for php, specifically what each terminal command does?**

I have been learning web development for 6 months and it is time I need the console / terminal. I can't find any beginner walkthrough of using the terminal to add libraries and plugins to PHP. There are a lot of tutorials for specific steps or errors, but none start to finish. 

If you want specifics to make your example concrete, here is what I am trying to install:

The library I am installing: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/.

My directory for PHP on MAMP: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin

Thanks!
Don

**edit**: 
I figured out my specific issue, but I don't think I really understand what I did, so I can't repeat it by myself in any other situation. This thread can help a lot of new terminal users including myself. The type of response I am looking for would go like this:

Step 1: Open your terminal. (This is an alternative way to navigate and execute commands on files  on your computer).

Step 2: Find out where MAMP is installed however you like. Then go to your terminal, and type in `cd` followed by the path. `cd` stands for current directory and tells your terminal where it should execute its commands. The command you use will be very similar to this `cd /Applications/MAMP`. This will make your current directory MAMP.

Step 3: You are adding a library to PHP. So you need to go to the PHP folder in MAMP.... (please help us from this part!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked and it is available in pear channels.

```
# this is from their site
pear channel-discover phpquery-pear.appspot.com  
pear install phpquery/phpQuery
```

Of course, for Mac using MAMP, you would use commands like this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear install [package]
```

So for PHPQuery, try this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear channel-discover phpquery-pear.appspot.com
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear install phpquery/phpQuery
```

Same method should apply to `pecl` extensions as well.

EDIT

I personally just installed it on mine to test, here were my results:

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear channel-discover phpquery-pear.appspot.com
Adding Channel "phpquery-pear.appspot.com" succeeded
Discovery of channel "phpquery-pear.appspot.com" succeeded
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear install phpquery/phpQuery
downloading phpQuery-0.9.5.386-pear.tgz ...
Starting to download phpQuery-0.9.5.386-pear.tgz (100,990 bytes)
......................done: 100,990 bytes
install ok: channel://phpquery-pear.appspot.com/phpQuery-0.9.5.386
```

This should work with any PEAR or PECL extension. [Check out this page for a list of PEAR packages](http://pear.php.net/packages.php).

EDIT 2

Make sure `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php` is in your include path! That is where phpQuery.php will be located once you've downloaded the PEAR packages properly with MAMP.

---

EDIT 3

Per cshu's comment, he mentioned that **these packages are no longer maintained** and that you should use this instead:

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear channel-discover pear.querypath.org 
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear install querypath/QueryPath
```

Comment: Additionally, if you don't want to type the entire path to MAMP's pear, then you can create an alias:  `alias pear'/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear'`. Then you can just type the commands as normal (as seen on their site).

Comment: Okay, good so far thank you :) How do I check that the installation worked succesfully? Can I actually see the 'files' or whatever I installed somewhere on my computer?

Comment: @DonnyP add this to your file: `require 'phpQuery.php';`. Then try to instantiate some sort of object like so: `$doc = phpQuery::newDocument('<div/>');`. If it works with no errors then you'll know it worked. (I know it will work)

Comment: `donald-pinkuss-macbook-pro:bin dopinkus$ pear install phpquery/phpQuery
phpquery/phpQuery is already installed and is the same as the released version 0.9.5.386
install failed
donald-pinkuss-macbook-pro:bin dopinkus$ `  but when I try to instantiate I get the require error for not found. nclude_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php')  Thanks @mmmmshuddup

Comment: "I've got the same issue. The cause is that Mac OS X comes with a version of pear already installed. When you type "pear list" at the prompt, it checks your $PATH var and accesses /usr/bin/pear, instead of the PEAR that is installed with MAMP."  Never mind the `alias` command I told you about. Use `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear` when installing

Comment: Also, make sure PEAR is in your include path.  `echo get_include_path();` and see if it's in there. If not, you'll need to add '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php' to your include path

Comment: It appears this package is no longer maintained - https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/issues/detail?id=227

You should use:  
`[path to pear] channel-discover pear.querypath.org  `
`[path to pear] install querypath/QueryPath`